# Can't insert into MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert an object in `MongoDB` with `Mongoose`, but without success.
In './models/user,js' I have:

```
var mongoDatabase = require('./db'); //I've connected to localhost here
var database = mongoDatabase.getDb();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
  user: String,
  adress: String,
});

userSchema.methods.testmethod = function(){
  console.log('test');
}
userSchema.methods.insert = function (obj) { //this works but what is the point to use Mongoose If I do it that way
  database.collection("users").insertOne(obj, function(err, res) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
}
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

In './controllers/user.js'

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var User    = require('../models/user');

router.post("/", function(request, response) {  
    var obj = new User({
        user: request.body.name,
        adress: request.body.adress,
    });

    obj.testmethod(); //works fine
    obj.insert(obj); //throws an error

    User.insertOne(obj, function(err, res) { //error: insertOne is not a function
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
    }); 
});
module.exports = router;
```

I have tried few more ways to do it, but without result. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `obj.save(function(err,res) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using whatever mongodb object you're creating in './db' to do this work, mongoose takes care of it for you.  Try simplifying down to this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
  user: String,
  adress: String,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then in your controller code

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var User    = require('../models/user');

router.post("/", function(request, response, next) {  
    var user = new User({
        user: request.body.name,
        adress: request.body.adress,
    });

    user.save(function(err, u) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.json(u);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Somewhere in your app startup code (often in app.js or similar location) you'll want to call `mongoose.connect(<connection url>)`, normally prior to setting up routes.

Note you can also call `insert()` explicitly, but it's a static method on the model object, like so:

`User.insert({user: 'bob', address: 'somewhere, nh'}, cb)`

Comment: Thank you! Last thing I'd like to know is what would one `return next(err)` instead of `throw err`?

Comment: If you're in asynchronous code, it's always appropriate to handle the error via callback (e.g. the error-first callback approach or by listening for an error event).  Throwing the error will not be catchable elsewhere in your app unless you're using the async/await stuff that's new to the latest version of Node.  next(err) is the Express-standard way of passing an error from inside a route, and then you'd mount an error handling middleware to deal with the errors you pop up in a common and centralized manner. Example: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html